# MS Access Query with Parameter does not work with php / sql

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I have an access database which i connect with php odbc.
Problem occurs when i access a query with php which have ms access parameters (Pop up in access for parameter entry) associated with it.

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

My code is as below:

```
<?php 

    function od_get_test() {
        // Executing Query ...
        global $cnx;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM qry_DailyIssued WHERE Issue=1 " ; // Issue is a ms access query parameter
        $od_flat_stock = odbc_exec($cnx, $query);
        confirm_query($od_flat_stock);
        return $od_flat_stock;
    }

     $od_test = od_get_test();

?>
```

Comment: What would you like to happen instead? I mean, it's server-side code so you don't have a user sitting in front of a desktop where you can display prompts.

Comment: I want that parameter to be specified in php query. The parameter is "Issue" Which is not working as defined in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the asked for parameter *name* and *value*:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM qry_DailyIssued WHERE Issue=1 AND [NameOfParameter] = " & SomeValue & ""
```

or, if the value is Text:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM qry_DailyIssued WHERE Issue=1 AND [NameOfParameter] = '" & SomeValue & "'"
```

Comment: I have already given the parameter. See comment in code. "Issue" is the parameter that pops up during access execution of query.

Comment: If you had, you wouldn't see the error. So, either is `Issue` misspelled or non-existing, or `qry_DailyIssued` has a second parameter you don't know of.

Comment: No that is not the case. I have tried in two different queries and same error comes for parameter. If i remove the parameter, it just runs.

Comment: Double-check. The only other option would be that _Issue_ is a reserved word, thus should be wrapped in brackets, `[Issue]`, but I don't think that is the case.